# Defining a variable once inside an infinite loop C++

Tags: c++, oop, while-loop

I'm using Pylon SDK in my project. It's a SDK for Basler cameras.

I'm calling `gimbalControl` function in an infinite while loop in the `main` function.

In `gimbalControl`, I need to define variables and initialize the gimbal parts. Afterwards, I use those initialized and defined things in the rest of the function. Following is a sample of my code clarifying the problem.

```
void gimbalControl(void)
{
   try
   {
        // Only executed in the first iteration
        if(!gimbalInitialized)
        {
             setupGimbal();
             configConnection(); 
             PylonInitialize();

             // Create an instant camera object with the camera device found first.
             CInstantCamera camera(CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice());

             // Open the camera before accessing any parameters
             camera.Open();

             // Start the grabbing of images
             camera.StartGrabbing();

             gimbalInitialized = true;
       }
       else
       {
            // Wait for an image and then retrieve it. A timout of 5000 ms is used.
            camera.RetrieveResult(5000, ptrGrabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);  // CAUSES ERROR

            // Image not grabbed successfully?
            if (!ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded())
            {
                cout << "Cannot capture a frame from video stream" << endl;
            }
    }
    catch(...) // Catch all unhandled exceptions
    {
        printf("ERROR IN CAMERA CONNECTION\n");
    }
}
```

I tried to make this module class-based but I didn't know how to declare camera in the class to be used later in the object. Actually, I don't know what this kind of `camera` declaration is!

When I compile this code I got an error that `camera was not declared in this scope`. 
**Question 1**: How can I define camera once in this infinite loop without raising this error?

**Question 2**: How can I declare `camera` as a private variable inside a class?

Comment: I cannot see **any** loop in this program, however, the `[...] was not declared in this scope` suggests that you did not declare your type. Are you sure that `camera` declaration is visible to your function?

Comment: @Fureeish His `gimbalControl` function is called in a loop.

Comment: Makes sense, my bad for not reading carefully. The suggestion about ensuring visibility, however, remains

Comment: is `gimbalControl` a class method or a global function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to make `camera` static outside the `try` block:

```
static CInstantCamera camera(CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice());
try {
    ...
} catch (...) {
    ...
}
```

This ensures that `camera` object gets initialized only once, and stays accessible on both sides of the `else` in the conditional.

To declare `camera` in your class, put `CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice()` in the initializer list:

```
class MyClass {
private:
    CInstantCamera camera;
public:
    MyClass() : camera(CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice()) {
    }
};
```

Comment: It works. I don't know how couldn't I think about this simple solution. Thanks.
Could you tell me how can I declare `camera` in a class to be used later by the objects?

Answer (score 2):

`camera` is just a regular initialization. In this case, you're just calling the constructor on `CInstantCamera` that takes whatever type `CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice()` is as the only argument.

Scopes for all intents and purposes define the lifetime of objects. One object cannot realistically talk to another in a different scope, unless they share a parent scope. In this case, `camera` is defined within the scope of the first `if` conditional block scope, but you reference it in the `else` conditional block scope.

```
void gimbalControl(void)
{
   // scope #1

   try
   {
        // scope #2 (inherits #1)

        if(!gimbalInitialized)
        {
            // scope #3 (inherits #1, #2)
        }
        else
        {
            // scope #4 (inherits #1, #2)
        }
    }
    catch(...) 
    {
        // scope #5 (inherits #1)
    }
}
```

Notice how scope **4** only inherits **1** and **2**, and not **3**? They are in the same parent level scope, so they do not have the same lifetimes. Objects cannot talk to each other (reasonably) within these scopes.

The solution, is to just initialize `camera` in scope **2**. Since you are calling this in a loop, you will need to make the declaration `static`, so that it's not constructed during each call, just the first one.

**References** - [Scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope), [Storage Duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) - see: *static*